# Perform ROC curve for logistic regression that uses the "weights" argument in R's glm

Tags: r, roc

I'm currently running a logistic regression that requires the use of the "whights" argument in the `glm` function as following:

```
model <-glm(cr ~kw_url+row_number+domn*plform+score100,family=binomial,weights=weights,data=glm_data)

head(glm_data[cr>0 & cr <1]) 
   kw_url  plform row_number   domn score    cr weights score100
1:  other Desktop          0 ***  0.25 0.007407407     135       25
2:  other Desktop          0 d***  0.24 0.011494253      87       24
3:  other  Mobile          0 ***  0.14 0.001414427     707       14
4:  other  Mobile          1 ***  0.43 0.013888889     144       43
5:  other  Mobile          2 ***  0.38 0.027027027      37       38
6:  other  Mobile          1 ***  0.48 0.014285714      70       48

head(glm_data[cr>0 & cr <1,.(cr)]) #Dependant variable is a fraction!, not 0 or 1
            cr
1: 0.007407407
2: 0.011494253
3: 0.001414427
4: 0.013888889
5: 0.027027027
6: 0.014285714
```

I'm usually using the `pROC` or the `ROCR` libraries for performing `ROC` curves, though they require the the regression's dependent variable to be either 0 or 1, but not a fraction.

Due to this issue, i'm getting the following error:

```
library(ROCR)
> p <- predict(bayes_model, newdata=glm_data, type="response")
> pr <- prediction(p, glm_data$cr)
Error in prediction(p, glm_data$cr) : 
  Number of classes is not equal to 2.
ROCR currently supports only evaluation of binary classification tasks
```

So my question is : is there some R package out there that produces ROC curve, and supports R's `glm` function with weighted data?

Comment: ROC curve is used to assess how well you model classifies one class versus another (or multiple other which you treat as one class then). In this case you need another metric/plot to assess performance since you are not predicting classes. the weights don't matter in this case.

Comment: glm with weights and family=binomial is a logistic regression model with 2 classes 1 or 0,  the aggregation is just just an efficient format in a group by stile, its not a model for continues data

Comment: I see. in that case you could unfold the data, e.g. for 0.007407407 add 135 zeros and a single 1 to get the data to work with e.g. ROC package.

Comment: Unfolding the data is exactly what im trying to avoid, its huge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this then. It is not a package, but should get the ROC. `prob` are the probabilities from the logistic regression. If this is still too many points  then just take a sample.

```
d <- data.frame(cr = c(1/212, 1/142, 1/15*2, 10/16, 10/3), 
                weight = c(212, 142, 15, 16, 3), 
                prob = c(1/200, 1/100, 1/35, 1/2, .7))


d$N <- (1 + d$cr) * d$weight
d$y <- d$cr * d$weight
o <- order(d$prob)
d <- d[o,]

N <- sum(d$y)
TOT <- sum(d$N)

x.plot <- cumsum(d$y) / N
y.plot <- cumsum(d$N) / (TOT - N)


plot(x.plot, y.plot, type = 'b')
```